# How To Create A Center Point At UIImageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

[image]

Hi Guys I am trying to rotate a UIImageview from the Black dot on this image.
what is happening now is that the center is not changing 
I have tried like this.

```
Image.Center = CGPointmake(37.3,150);
```

when I am calling this set the image just moves across the screen.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this code:-

```
    imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];

imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: center point around which you need to rotate and its value is between 0 to 1

Comment: Nothing Work   

 Needle.center = CGPointMake(37.5,150);
    Needle.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
    
    Needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(Slider.value);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: don't set center point. and this code worked fr me as i created clock app using this simple code.

Comment: it is rotate but from the center. i want the center to be lower at the black dot

Comment: it works! do you know why the image is jumping when it starts?

Comment: try to set anchor point i did it by trying various anchor points between 0 to 1